# How does layout.jade and its children work?

Tags: express, pug

I am learning express 4.0 and the tutorial uses layout.jade and some children jade.

They connect `block content` and `extends layout`
In my layout.jade file, there is only one `block content`.

However I have three jade files that start `extends layout` and `block content`.

How does jade know what to put inside of layout.jade?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade fills in the blocks of the parent template based on the matching blocks defined in the extending child you are rendering. It helps to to keep your code more DRY.

Comment: What does it mean DRY? It seems like parent template matches 3 jade files. You can look at them here https://github.com/cleechtech/express-todo/tree/master/views  I am sure I miss some point or don't understand concept well.

Comment: DRY means "do not repeat yourself" and in this case you render the child template which inherits from the parent and substitutes in the relevant blocks. This way you can make more children without redefining everything in layout as long as they follow the same layout.